# Microsoft Bot Builder - How to send PromptDialog to the custom created Activity?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

In short the main task is receive a message from one user and forward it to another. So that I've got the construction below:

```
public class ForwardDialog : IDialog<bool>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        string ServiceUrl = "http://localhost:56675";
        string OriginalMessageSenderName = "Test";
        string OriginalMessageSenderId = "TestId";
        string OriginalMessageText = "sd";
        ChannelAccount BotAccount = new ChannelAccount(
            name: "Bot", 
            id: "default-bot"
        );
        ChannelAccount UserAccount = new ChannelAccount(
            name: "User", 
            id: "default-user"
        );
        ConnectorClient ForwardClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(ServiceUrl));
        ConversationResourceResponse ForwardConversation = ForwardClient.Conversations.CreateDirectConversation(BotAccount, UserAccount);

        ForwardMessage.From = BotAccount;
        ForwardMessage.Recipient = UserAccount;
        ForwardMessage.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: ForwardConversation.Id);
        ForwardMessage.Text = $"{OriginalMessageSenderName}: {OriginalMessageText}";
        ForwardMessage.Locale = "ru-ru";

        //ForwardClient.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)ForwardMessage);

        PromptDialog.Text(context, PostResultAsync, "Reply", "What?", 3);
    }

    private async Task PostResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> prompt)
    {
        var result = await prompt;
        await context.PostAsync($"{result}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

SendToConversation works perfectly, but I need to send PromptDialog and that's the problem. The context I'm passing to PromptDialog sends a message to the first user, but I need it does send the message to the second one. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to do it in the as part of the MessageReceived of the message you are forwarding to the other user.

Comment: That's what I do, don't I? I've tried to create a separate Dialog class and call it as a child dialog, but the context I receive there is the same context from the original message.

Comment: You are doing that right after the message is being sent to the other user... in the context of the first user!. Where you receive the message? Is the same bot or is there another one?

Comment: The prompt dialog needs to be instantiated on the other end of the conversation (on the second user receiving the message) you can't send a prompt dialog from one user to another one.

Comment: It's the same bot. The thing is I can't wait any requests from the second user to open new context, I create a proactive activity and forward to him the message I received from the first user. No, I don't need to do something like send a prompt dialog to first user and return the answer to second. I need to receive a message from the first user then send it to the second user as is and then request a reply from the second user by sending him a prompt dialog.